# can't able to click listView item in tabhost

Tags: android, android-listview, android-tabhost

[onItemClick listener in ListView is not working in TabHost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692072/onitemclick-listener-in-listview-is-not-working-in-tabhost)

I visited this URL.I don't get waht is he tring to do. here aare my code.

```
dineTypeTabHost=getTabHost();
dineTypeTabHost.addTab(dineTypeTabHost.newTabSpec("").setIndicator("",
getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.search_icon)).setContent(R.id.tab_search));

 foodlistViewForTakeAway=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.tab_takeaway);
```

//setting the onitemselectedlistener & this is working fine in emulator but not in phone

```
 foodlistViewForTakeAway.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            //              makeAToast("eiv to");
            goToMenuActivity();
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

But this is not working,either phone or emulator whenever I tried to setOnItemClickListener

```
foodlistViewForTakeAway.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            goToMenuActivity();
        }

    });
```

please have a look thanx in advance,let me know if u need any elaboration.

myxml file:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="Food Joint name"
    android:textColor="#0AFFFF"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView_cus"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView_name"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:text="Cuisine:"
    android:textColor="#FFFF0A"
    android:textSize="12dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView_loc"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TextView_cus"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="Location:"
    android:textColor="#FFFF0A"
    android:textSize="12dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView_cnt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TextView_loc"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="Contacts:"
    android:textColor="#FFFF0A"
    android:textSize="12dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_cuisine"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/TextView_loc"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextView_cnt"
    android:text="japani,thai,khai"
    android:textColor="#FFFF0A"
    android:textSize="12dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_location"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/TextView_cnt"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView_cuisine"
    android:text="Kolkata,Saltlake,Sector-2"
    android:textColor="#FFFF0A"
    android:textSize="12dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_contact"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView_cnt"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView_cnt"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView_location"
    android:text="9893939833,033-28399839"
    android:textColor="#FFFF0A"
    android:textSize="12dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView_fac"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView_contact"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView_cuisine"
    android:text="Facilities:"
    android:textColor="#FFFF0A"
    android:textSize="12dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_facility"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView_fac"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView_fac"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView_contact"
    android:text="Wifi,AC/Non AC,Parking"
    android:textColor="#FFFF0A"
    android:textSize="12dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView_opn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView_fac"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TextView_fac"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="Open Hours:"
    android:textColor="#FFFF0A"
    android:textSize="12dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView_contact"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView_contact"
    android:background="@drawable/veg_symbol" />
```

Comment: Remove `setOnItemSelectedListener` .Use only `OnItemClickListener`.

Comment: thnx padma kumar.please help me out here.

Comment: dear samir the thing is "setOnItemSelectedListener " is working in emulator. "OnItemClickListener" is not working at all.and i am not using both of them at a time.

Comment: if `foodlistViewForTakeAway` is listview then always use `OnItemClickListener` and try to print in `onItemClick` method...what happens////

Comment: What contains in the listview item

Comment: @dreamtale 5 textviews and 1 button.

Comment: @kaushik see my answer, hope that can help you.

Comment: @dreamtale shuld I use that in case of that button too.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765120/onlistitemclick-is-not-working-for-listview) i answered before. Hope that can help you.

Try below code, add to the view in the item in your XML layout.

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
```